# Optimize current MySQL query of 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, table1 and table2. Both have about 500000 records each. They have 2 similar columns, cid and year, both not unique (different year for each cid)

```
table1 columns: cid, year, status
tables2 columns: cid, year, acc, rej
```

When I make a query with a LIMIT 50, it already takes about half a minute to process. I'd like to optimize this query.

Here is my current query

```
SELECT table1.cid, acc, rej, table1.year 
FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.status != 0 
AND table1.year = 2015 
AND table1.year = table2.year 
AND table1.cid = table.cid
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index on table1 (cid,year) and table2 (cid,year) , it should speed up your query.

Also, please avoid the use of IMPLICIT join syntax(comma separated) and use the explicit syntax like this:

```
SELECT table1.cid, acc, rej, table1.year 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
 ON(table1.year = table2.year and table1.cid = table.cid)
WHERE table1.status != 0 
 AND table1.year = 2015 
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: wow. adding the index is the solution. worked perfectly. query took 10x faster (from 32sec to 2.9sec) thanks!

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Why? won't it pick 50 random records? @Strawberry

Comment: @sagi No. ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50 would pick 50 random rows. Your query picks indeterminate rows. It's not the same thing.